# Pandas DataFrame - How to change my headers to date format from 2021-03-01 00:00:00 to Mar-21

Tags: pandas, header, format

I have read an excel file as dataframe.
I dropped some columns that I dont need
I have some date columns from Jan-21 through to Dec-21 in excel but in data frame the  header is displaying these months as "2021-03-01 00:00:00"as an example for March 21

The column index's for date format columns start from column index 10 to 22.

How can this format be changed to customise the headers to "Mar-21" format

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​

df_FC= pd.read_excel('TOM Snapshot 17.12.20.xlsx', sheet_name='Clarity Forecast')
df_TOM = pd.read_excel('TOM Snapshot 17.12.20.xlsx', sheet_name='TOM',  header= None)
​
data =  df_TOM.copy()
#drops first row
data.drop(0, inplace =True)
​
#Renamed the column header based on what is in the first row
data = data.rename(columns=data.iloc[0]) 
#Drops the 2nd index row
data.drop(1, inplace =True)
data.head()

data.columns = data.columns.astype("str")
​
data1 = data.iloc[:, [0,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,67,68,69,70,75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]]

data1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionnary to rename the date columns: ```data.rename(columns={"2021-03-01 00:00:00": "Mar-21"}, inplace=True)```. If that's it, then extend the dictionnary with all the columns you want to rename

Answer (score 1):

From your text description I think you are trying to rename your pd.DataFrame column headers from pandas.timestamp format "2021-03-01 00:00:00" to "Mar-21" format.

Note: This should also work if it is in python datetime.datetime

First make a sample DataFrame example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10], ['B', 9], ['C', 8]], columns=([datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1), datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1)]))

df
  2021-03-01 00:00:01  2021-04-01 00:00:01
0                   A                   10
1                   B                    9
2                   C                    8

print(type(df.columns[0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Hopefully this is close to what you have. Now convert into the desired format Mar-01

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b-%d')
df
  Mar-01  Apr-01
0      A      10
1      B       9
2      C       8
```

Note: The strftime converts from pandas.timestamp to a string

```
print(type(df.columns[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

Link to the strftime options
https://strftime.org/